# Does Google Analytics Implementation required signed apk to be tracked

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is there any requirement to install only signed apk in order to get live data through Google Anaytics.
I have implemented google anaytics as per google instructions from "https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/", but not getting live data in debugging, means the number of active users in analytics is still 0.
Please help me out, or suggest me instructions to implement google analytics in my app.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how long did you wait? if its a new Google analytics account it can take up to 72 hours to start showing data.  after that time data should start showing up in the realtime reports.

Comment: yeah its a new account but it use to give live data right...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take 24-48 hours for a new google analytics account to start showing data but later it will be instant as its going right now.
for sample app as reference, take the help of sample in SDK under extra folder, its perfect.

Thanks to DalmTo for this answer (in comments section)

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Analytics will upload data from application even if the application is not signed or installed from Google Play Store. You probably either have dry run mode enabled (check if you have made a call to [GoogleAnalytics.setDryRun(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#setDryRun(boolean)) or set dry run mode in your Analytics XML configuration) or your tracker is miss-configured (missing or wrong tracker id).

Try setting the logging to verbose temporary and check your logcat:

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
..
     analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
     // Remove before ship. Do not ship your application with verbose log level!
     analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
```

Comment: cross checked the tracker id, its perfect. where to call this setDryRun(true) ??? n what it will do.

Comment: setDryRun(boolean) is a method of GoogleAnalytics singleton. I linked the the text from the answer to the API reference. setDryRun(true) will make the SDK do everything as it would normally do, except actually sending the data to Google Analytics server. Its a development flag that one can use while working on the app to prevent it from polluting the real app reports.